# Quartz: scheduling with intervals by job family

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am evaluating schedulers, and I wonder whether quartz has the following functionality.

The problem: I have jobs which are separated to families of jobs.

For example:

- Family A: job A1, job A2, ... job An
- Family B: job B1, job B2, ... job Bm
- etc

So I want to define a time interval for each family, and when I schedule a job from specific family, the job will be scheduled with an interval from the last job scheduled of that family.

I would really appreciate to know whether quartz has such capability.

Comment: I can suggest you google and then read manual about `quartz`

Comment: Andremoniy, thanks for the suggestion